# Read CID from SD card with ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, sd-card

I would like to get the serial numbers of SD cards, with follow code:

```c++
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// set up variables using the SD utility library functions:
Sd2Card card;
SdVolume volume;
SdFile root;

cid_t cid;  // *****at the top with the other globals (for get cid)

// change this to match your SD shield or module;
// Arduino Ethernet shield: pin 4
// Adafruit SD shields and modules: pin 10
// Sparkfun SD shield: pin 8
const int chipSelect = 4;

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  Serial.print("\nInitializing SD card...");

  // we'll use the initialization code from the utility libraries
  // since we're just testing if the card is working!
  if (!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed. Things to check:");
    Serial.println("* is a card inserted?");
    Serial.println("* is your wiring correct?");
    Serial.println("* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?");
    return;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wiring is correct and a card is present.");
  }

  // print the type of card
  Serial.print("\nCard type: ");
  switch (card.type()) {
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SD1:
      Serial.println("SD1");
      break;
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SD2:
      Serial.println("SD2");
      break;
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SDHC:
      Serial.println("SDHC");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown");
  }

  // Now we will try to open the 'volume'/'partition' - it should be FAT16 or FAT32
  if (!volume.init(card)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find FAT16/FAT32 partition.\nMake sure you've formatted the card");
    return;
  }


  // print the type and size of the first FAT-type volume
  uint32_t volumesize;
  Serial.print("\nVolume type is FAT");
  Serial.println(volume.fatType(), DEC);
  Serial.println();

  volumesize = volume.blocksPerCluster();    // clusters are collections of blocks
  volumesize *= volume.clusterCount();       // we'll have a lot of clusters
  volumesize *= 512;                            // SD card blocks are always 512 bytes
  Serial.print("Volume size (bytes): ");
  Serial.println(volumesize);
  Serial.print("Volume size (Kbytes): ");
  volumesize /= 1024;
  Serial.println(volumesize);
  Serial.print("Volume size (Mbytes): ");
  volumesize /= 1024;
  Serial.println(volumesize);

  Serial.println();

  // *****list all files in the card with date and size
  //Serial.println("\nFiles found on the card (name, date and size in bytes): ");
  //root.openRoot(volume);
  //root.ls(LS_R | LS_DATE | LS_SIZE);

  card.readCID(&cid);
  Serial.print("Serial number: "); Serial.println(cid.src); // psn is the serial number field of the struct

}

void loop(void) {

}
```

I tried to get serial from SD card but I only get this "Serial number: 2065301974". I really need it in hex format, for example "0x0033515c".

Also, I would like to get the complete CID like this:

```
CID: 0x1B, 0x53, 0x4D, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x10, 0x45, 0x5D, 0x04, 0xE5, 0x00, 0xF9, 0x69
```

Comment: TLDR. Is your question "how do I convert a decimal string into a hex number"?

Comment: I see no "src" in the cid_t structure....

Comment: the CID is not a true "serial number" it's easily hackable. don't use this for security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cid_t` is a structure that has all sorts of information in it in different formats.  The serial number (`psn`) is just a 32-bit unsigned integer.  You can print it as hex by printing it as hex.

```
Serial.println(cid.psn, HEX);
```

If you want to get the raw data of the structure (which I assume may correspond to the raw data read from the card, but don't quote me on that) you can access the struct as 8-bit values:

```
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)&cid;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cid); i++) {
    Serial.print("0x");
    Serial.print(p[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
}
Serial.println();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this and I got: 12 10 17 4D 49 42 53 54 2 0 0 5 A2 0 19 11 0 0 0 0 I know that is wrong because I got serial of sd card on linux and the real serial number ir "0x000005a2" and what I really want is the complete cid number as shown here a.d-cd.net/ec9effas-960.jpg I´m very grateful –

Comment: These are the data obtained from Linux: cid: 041641534d492d534403000000001601 serial: 0x03000000 And these are the data obtained from ESP8266: cid (with your code): 1210174E4361726410001C5019AF0000 serial (whit cid.psn): 0xAF1900C5 Then, apparently it is not showing the correct dada... I think something is wrong with the code. Please help me.

Comment: How are you getting the data in Linux?

Comment: The CID I find in this file SYS->BLOCK->MMCBLK0->DEVICE->cid and the serial I find in this file SYS->BLOCK->MMCBLK0->DEVICE->serial

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the right device?

Comment: Yes, because when I disconnect the sd card... this folder "MMCBLK0" disappears... and when I connect the sd card... this folder "MMCBLK0" appears... Is it OK?

Comment: What device are you using for this test? (the Linux device I mean)...?

Comment: The Linux kernel handles two different formats of CID. Maybe that has something to do with it. The source is [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.13/source/drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c#L70).

Comment: I think I need get raw cid. Any idea for get on Arduino? The complete CID (32 digits, like this: 041641534d492d534403000000001601)

Answer (score 0):

To print the serial number in hex [Serial.println](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/) accepts a format parameter:

```
Serial.println(cid.psn, HEX);
```

The cid variable is a struct so you can access the the other fields via the structure. But if you really want to access the raw bytes you could cast cid to a pointer then access the individual bytes:

```
uint8_t *rawcid = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&cid);
Serial.println(*(cid+3), HEX); // print the 4th byte
```

Be aware that casting like this can be tricky and you will likely shoot yourself in the foot more than once.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this and I got: 12 10 17 4D 49 42 53 54 2 0 0 5 A2 0 19 11 0 0 0 0

I know that is wrong because I got serial of sd card on linux and the real serial number ir "0x000005a2" and what I really want is the complete cid number as shown here https://a.d-cd.net/ec9effas-960.jpg 

I´m very grateful

Comment: The serial number is just a small part of the Cid. You can see 0 0 5 A2 which as uint32_t is 000005a2 in the string of bytes you have.

Comment: These are the data obtained from Linux:

cid: 041641534d492d534403000000001601
serial: 0x03000000

And these are the data obtained from ESP8266:

cid (with your code): 1210174E4361726410001C5019AF0000
serial (whit cid.psn): 0xAF1900C5

Then, apparently it is not showing the correct dada...

I think something is wrong with the code.

Please help me.